# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Song with id=vote_for) [rails4]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I'm having trouble getting the Thumbs Up gem workin'.

When I click the up arrow to vote up or down I seem to be gettin' the following msg in the rails logs:

**Error logs:**

```
I, [2013-07-24T19:49:39.719359 #13941]  INFO -- : Started PUT "/songs//vote_for" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-24 19:49:39 -0400
I, [2013-07-24T19:49:39.719444 #13941]  INFO -- : Started PUT "/songs//vote_for" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-24 19:49:39 -0400
F, [2013-07-24T19:49:39.729009 #13941] FATAL -- : 
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Song with id=vote_for):
  app/controllers/songs_controller.rb:87:in `set_song'
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<div id="layout1">

<h3>Songs</h3>

<ol>
<% @songs.each do |song| %>
 <li><%= link_to song.title, song %><br></li>

<%=link_to  '&#9650'.html_safe, vote_for_song_path(@song), :remote => true, :method => :put %> 
 <%=link_to '&#9660'.html_safe, vote_against_song_path(@song), :remote => true, :method => :put %> |

    Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(song.created_at) + " ago" %>
    <span class="comments"> | <%= pluralize(song.comments.size, 'comment') %></span> | <span class="votes"><%= pluralize(song.votes.count, 'vote') %></span><br />



<%#= link_to 'Show', song, class: "button small secondary" %>
<%= link_to('Edit', edit_song_path(song), class: "button small secondary") if can? :update, @song %>
<%= link_to('Destroy', song, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, class: "button small secondary") if can? :destroy, @song %>


<% end %>

</ol>
</div>


<br />
</div>
```

**song_controller.rb**

```
class SongsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:create ,:edit, :update, :destroy, :vote_for_song]
  before_action :set_song, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :vote_for_song]


  def vote_for_song
      @song = Song.find(params[:id])
      current_user.vote_for(@song)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render 'update_votes' }
      end
  end

  def vote_against_song
    @song = Song.find(params[:id])
    current_user.vote_against(@song)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render 'update_votes' }
    end
  end


  # GET /Songs
  # GET /Songs.json
  def index
    @songs = Song.all
  end

  # GET /Songs/1
  # GET /Songs/1.json
  def show
   @comment = Comment.new(song: @song)
  end

  # GET /Songs/new
  def new
    @song = Song.new
  end

  # GET /Songs/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /Songs
  # POST /Songs.json
  def create
    @song = Song.new(song_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @song.save
        format.html { redirect_to @song, notice: 'Song was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @song }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @song.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /Songs/1
  # PATCH/PUT /Songs/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @song.update(song_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @song, notice: 'Song was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @song.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # Song /Songs/1
  # Song /Songs/1.json
  def destroy
    @song.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to songs_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def set_song
       @song = Song.find(params[:id])
     end

     def song_params
       params.require(:song).permit(:title, :artist, :bio, :track, :user_id)
     end
  end
```

**song.rb**

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_voteable

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy


has_attached_file :track,
                  :url  => "/assets/songs/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                  :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/songs/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"


  validates_attachment :track, :presence => true

  validates :title, length: { minimum: 10 }
  validates :bio, length: { maximum: 300 }



end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :songs
  has_many :comments

  acts_as_voter

end
```

**vote.rb**

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :for_voter, lambda { |*args| where(["voter_id = ? AND voter_type = ?", args.first.id, args.first.class.base_class.name]) }
  scope :for_voteable, lambda { |*args| where(["voteable_id = ? AND voteable_type = ?", args.first.id, args.first.class.base_class.name]) }
  scope :recent, lambda { |*args| where(["created_at > ?", (args.first || 2.weeks.ago)]) }
  scope :descending, lambda { order("created_at DESC") }

  belongs_to :voteable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :voter, :polymorphic => true

  attr_accessible :vote, :voter, :voteable if ActiveRecord::VERSION::MAJOR < 4


  # Comment out the line below to allow multiple votes per user.
  validates_uniqueness_of :voteable_id, :scope => [:voteable_type, :voter_type, :voter_id]

end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Leap2::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :comments

  devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'registrations'}
  resources :songs do
    member do
      put :vote_for, :vote_against
    end
  end


  get '/contact', to: 'songs#contact'
  get '/faq', to: 'songs#faq'

  root to: 'songs#index'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these two lines of `index.html.erb`, replace `@song` with `song` and it should work:

```
<%=link_to  '&#9650'.html_safe, vote_for_song_path(@song), :remote => true, :method => :put %> 
 <%=link_to '&#9660'.html_safe, vote_against_song_path(@song), :remote => true, :method => :put %> |
```

Also the same for these two lines:

```
<%= link_to('Edit', edit_song_path(song), class: "button small secondary") if can? :update, @song %>
<%= link_to('Destroy', song, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, class: "button small secondary") if can? :destroy, @song %>
```

Comment: thanks my man. i can vote up and it works now :) but when i click the down arrow nothin' happens. why's that?

Comment: No problem - glad to help. Watch your development log while you click the down arrows and see if your browser is sending correct remote requests. If it isn't, there's something else wrong with the link. If it is, watch for any error or info messages that provide a clue.

Comment: If you are seeing down-votes come in, check in the rails console to see if the vote data actually changes when you vote against. That will help isolate if the problem is in the request, or whether there may be something going wrong during `render 'update_votes'` in the `vote_against_song` controller action.

Comment: this is what comes in: F, [2013-07-24T22:06:34.633751 #14378] FATAL -- : 
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Voteable has already been taken):
  app/controllers/songs_controller.rb:16:in `vote_against'

Comment: Ah - well, the good news is that this isn't a bug! From the documentation: "ThumbsUp by default only allows one vote per user. This can be changed by removing..." See here: https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up#one-vote-per-user